# Stabilizer of a Levi subgroup in the Weyl group and its quotient

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups, reductive-groups, root-systems, weyl-group

(I appologize in advance if this question is too naive for experts, since I know very little about the geometry/combinatorics of Weyl/Coxeter groups.)

For simplicity, let $G$ be a connected reductive group over $\mathbb{C}$, so that there's no harm identifying an algebraic group with the group of its $\mathbb{C}$-points, and $G$ is split of course. We fix a Borel subgroup $B=TU$ of $G$ with its Levi decomposition ($T$ a maximal torus of $G$ and $U$ its unipotent radical), and then we get the root system $\Phi=\Phi(G,T)$ together with a set of positive roots $\Phi^+$ and simple roots $\Delta\subset \Phi^+$. Let $W:=W^G=N_G(T)/T$ be the Weyl group of $(G,T)$.

Let $P$ be a standard (i.e. $P\supset B$) parabolic subgroup of $G$ with its Levi decomposition $P=MN$ where $N$ is the unipotent radical of $P$ and $M\supset T$ is a Levi subgroup of $P$. Then $P$ corresponds to a subset $\theta$ of $\Delta$  where $(\Delta-\theta)$ is the set of positive simple roots that appear in ${\rm Lie}\,N$.

I want to understand the following subgroup:
$$\mathcal{W}(M):= \{ w\in W\ |\ wMw^{-1}=M \},$$
i.e. the "stabilizer" of the Levi factor $M$. Let $W^M$ be the Weyl group of $(M,T)$, then in the literature (of representation theory of reductive groups over local fields) I usually see the quotient group
$$W(M):=\mathcal{W}(M)/W^M.$$
But I have no idea what it looks like. I know that $W^M$ is the Weyl group of the root subsystem generated by $\theta\subset \Delta$, but what can we say about the subgroup $\mathcal{W}(M)$ and the quotient $W(M)$? Is there any related theorem? To be more concrete, I'm interested in questions:

- How to characterize $\mathcal{W}(M)$ and $W(M)$ geometrically (via root systems)?
- Can we compute the order of $W(M)$?
- Can we know anything more explicitly in the case when $P$ is a maximal parabolic ($\Delta-\theta=\{\alpha\}$)? For example, based on some examples, I guess that in the maximal case $|W(M)|$ can only be $1$ or $2$; is this right?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help/information!

Comment: $W$ does not act on $G$. What do you precisely mean? Do you want to use $N(T)$ or the Tits extension instead??

Comment: @BugsBunny Ah, I’m sorry that I should write $wMw^{-1}$ rather than $wM$ for the action. It’s just the elementwise conjugation (since the representative $w$ is differ by an element of $T$, the conjugate Levi is well defined).

Comment: If you really need an answer, I would suggest to explain all notations. In particular, what are $M$ and  $N$?

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi Thanks! I forgot to explain their precise meanings. Now revised.   :)

Comment: @MikhailBorovoi Oh, thanks a lot for your edit and revision, professor!

Comment: $\mathcal W(M)$ is the subgroup of $W$ that preserves $\mathbb Z\theta$, and the map from $W(M)$ to the group of orthogonal transformations of $\mathbb Z\theta$, or of diagram automorphisms of the root system spanned by $\theta$, is an embedding.

Comment: @LSpice Thanks a lot; but could you please explain this in more detail? What do you mean by the "diagram automorphism" and how to see that $\mathcal{W}(M)$ is the subgroup that preserves $\mathbb{Z}\theta$?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456675/stabilizer-of-a-levi-subgroup-in-the-weyl-group-and-its-quotient#comment1183308_456675), an element of $\mathcal W(M)$ preserves $\Phi(M, T) = \mathbb Z\theta$; and an element of $W$ that preserves $\mathbb Z\theta = \Phi(M, T)$ preserves $T$ and carries all root subgroups for $T$ in $G$ corresponding to roots in $\Phi(M, T)$ into $M$, hence carries the group $M$ they generate into $M$.  A root system has a Dynkin diagram, and a diagram automorphism is literally just an automorphism of that diagram, viewed as a directed graph.

Comment: @LSpice Thanks. I think the only thing that I haven't really understood is: $\mathcal{W}(M)$ preserves $\mathbb{Z}\theta\cap \Phi=\Phi(M,T)$, thus $\mathcal{W}(M)$ acts on this root system, and it's larger than the Weyl group $W^M$ of $\Phi(M,T)$; but why the quotient group can be embedded into the graph automorphism group of this root system? Is this obvious?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456675/stabilizer-of-a-levi-subgroup-in-the-weyl-group-and-its-quotient#comment1183880_456675), a diagram automorphism is the same as an angle- and length-preserving permutation of the simple roots.  Take an element $w$ of $\mathcal W(M)$.  It carries $\theta$ to some other system $\theta'$ of simple roots for $\Phi(M, T)$, so there is an element $w'$ of $W^M$ that carries $\theta'$ to $\theta$.  Then $w'w$ belongs to the same coset of $W^M$ in $\mathcal W(M)$ as $w$, and is an angle- and length-preserving permutation of $\theta$.

Comment: @LSpice Ah, I understand. Now the only question for me is: when $M$ is a maximal Levi (corresponding to $\theta=\Delta-\{\alpha\}$), then $|W(M)|$ can only be $1$ or $2$. I carried out many experiments, but have not yet found a general proof. In Shahidi's Plancherel paper, $\tilde{w}_0\in W$ denotes the element such that $\tilde{w}_0\theta\subset \Delta$ and $\tilde{w}_0(\Delta-\theta)\subset \Phi^{-}$. I guess that when $M$ is maximal, $|W(M)|=2$ if and only if $\tilde{w}_0 M\tilde{w}_0^{-1}=M$, which is a crucial condition in Shahidi's theorem 8.1.

Comment: @LSpice Oh, I'm sorry. I made a mistake. My "guess" is not true: there's no relation between $|W(M)|=2$ and the condition $\tilde{w}_0M \tilde{w}_0^{-1}=M$. For $\mathrm{GL}(n)$, $|W(M)|=2$ if and only if $\tilde{w}_0M \tilde{w}_0^{-1}=M$. But for $\mathrm{Sp}(4)$, if we let $\theta=\{2\epsilon_2\}$, $\Delta-\theta=\{\epsilon_1-\epsilon_2\}$, $M_{\theta}\simeq \mathrm{GL}(1)\times \mathrm{SL}(2)$, then $\tilde{w}_0M \tilde{w}_0^{-1}\neq M$ and $|W(M)|=2$. But anyway, so far all the examples I have computed satisty $|W(M)|\leq 2$ ($M$ maximal).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments ([example](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456675/stabilizer-of-a-levi-subgroup-in-the-weyl-group-and-its-quotient#comment1183307_456675)), $\mathcal W(M)$ is the subgroup of $W$ that preserves $\mathbb Z\theta$, and the map from $W(M)$ to the group of orthogonal transformations of $\mathbb Z\theta$, or of diagram automorphisms of the root system spanned by $\theta$, is an embedding.

You then [asked](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456675/stabilizer-of-a-levi-subgroup-in-the-weyl-group-and-its-quotient#comment1184077_456675) whether $W(M)$ has order at most $2$ when $M$ is a maximal proper Levi subgroup of $G$, i.e., when $\theta$ misses exactly one simple root $\alpha$.  As we [discussed](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/456675/stabilizer-of-a-levi-subgroup-in-the-weyl-group-and-its-quotient#comment1183969_456675), every element $\overline w$ of $W(M)$ has a representative $w$ that preserves $\theta$.  Since $w\Delta$ spans $\Phi(G, T)$, we have that $w\alpha$ belongs to $\pm\alpha + \mathbb Z\theta$.  Suppose that $w\alpha$ belongs to $\alpha + \mathbb Z\theta$, hence to $\alpha + \mathbb Z_{\ge 0}\theta$.  Then $w$ sends every root in $\Delta$ to a positive root, hence every positive root to a positive root, hence is the trivial element of $W$.  Thus, any non-identity element of $ W(M)$ has a representative that preserves $\theta$, and carries $\alpha$ into $-\alpha + \mathbb Z\theta$; so any two non-identity elements have a quotient that preserves $\theta$, and carries $\alpha$ into $\alpha + \mathbb Z\theta$, and is therefore the identity.

Comment: @youknowwho, thank you for fixing my inconsistent notation.